# Can an app requiring ios 7+ be installed on a device that cannot update further than ios 6?

Tags: software-update

Most instructions show that when there's an opportunity for a software update. However, this is a different case, as the device you want to install on (lets say a 1st gen Ipad and you want to install an app that requires ios 7+). Is that possible, as the device cannot update further? Or does it require special programs?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer here is in the title: no. I'm not familiar enough with the platform to answer the technical details, but I'm guessing that API access changes version to version, and newer apps just won't have what they'll need on older platforms.

Comment: Very likely NO as per the other comment - I have many apps that demand to be updated due to system updates...

Answer (score 1):

No, you wouldn't be able to install the app. Depending on what the app is, it might need specific functionality that is not offered in iOS 6, but is offered in iOS 7+.